# Adding a callback to a SwiftUI Picker

Tags: callback, picker, swiftui

I'm trying to add a callback to a SwiftUI picker but can't get it to execute. The didSet apparently does not execute when picker value changes. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var picked: Int = 0 {didSet{print("here")}}
    var someData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $picked,
                   label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< someData.count)     {Text(self.someData[$0]).tag($0)}
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            Text("you picked: \(someData[picked])")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With iOS 14 there is `onChange`. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130311/78336

Answer (score 20):

**Code updated to beta 6**

The @State variable will never execute didSet, because it does not change. What does change is the wrapped value. So the only way I can think to tap it, is by putting a second binding in the middle, to serve as an intermediary, and pass the value along. This way, you can put your callback there.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var picked: Int = 0

    var someData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {

        let p = Binding<Int>(get: {
            return self.picked
        }, set: {
            self.picked = $0

            // your callback goes here
            print("setting value \($0)")
        })


        return VStack {
            Picker(selection: p,
                   label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< someData.count) {
                        Text(self.someData[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
            }
            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            Text("you picked: \(someData[picked])")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DOESNT COMPILE:   Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Comment: This works only half way. I can seem to make it work coming back. Say you want to convert the letter "b" passed in via binding and make that the selected button. I can't make it work

Comment: @jimijon that is a trivial problem, not related to SwiftUI: Simply look for the item index in the array: `self.picked =  self.someData.firstIndex(of: "b") ?? 0`

Comment: It's not. Try to pass the binding to view after it's been set. How does one set the binding:  @Binding alphabetLetter:String. ?   You need to then set self.picked to self.someData.first...   this causes then the infinite loop

Comment: Uau nice solution, works great! I needed this to update Binding variable coming from Parent View(s).

Answer (score 3):

you can use ObservableObject to workaround it

```
import SwiftUI

class PickerModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var picked: Int = 0 {didSet{print("here")}}
}

struct Picker_Callback: View {
   @ObservedObject var pickerModal = PickerModel()
    var someData = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Picker(selection: self.$pickerModal.picked,
                   label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< someData.count)     {Text(self.someData[$0]).tag($0)}
            }
            //.pickerStyle(.wheel)
            Text("you picked: \(someData[self.pickerModal.picked])")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `didSet` modifier on a variable with the `@State` property wrapper.

The `State` wrapper tells SwiftUI that the wrapped value must be managed by the SwiftUI framework itself. This means that the view doesn't actually contains the value, it only contains a `State` (which is immutable) that provide some kind of reference to the wrapped value.

Actually, you should forget about the `didSet` callback inside a SwiftUI `View`.
The `View` protocol requires a `body`, which **is not** marked as `mutating` (SwiftUI views are `struct`). So a `View` is basically immutable.

Comment: rraphael is 100% right. The didSet will never be called. Check my answer for a workaround.

Comment: The `.onChange` modifier (for a Picker, among other things) ***is*** available, which may be sufficient for some cases.