# How do I add action on picker on selection of item in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a picker with certain list of items (say- Add, Edit, Delete) and on selection on particular item, I need to move to a different screen. I tried onTapGuesture() but control does not go inside when I debug the same.

Comment: onChange function should work, then send a identifier which was selected and update a State to move to a new view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 3 different ways to achieve this. The last one I took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130311/9982386). So, there are all these ways, you can choose which you want:

```swift
struct PickerOnChange: View {

    private var options = ["add", "edit", "delete"]
    @State private var selectedOption = 0
    @State private var choosed = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Picker(selection: $selectedOption.onChange(changeViewWithThirdWay), label: Text("Choose action")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.options.count) {
                    Text(self.options[$0]).tag($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            // MARK: first way
            VStack {
                if selectedOption == 0 {
                    Text("add (first way)")
                } else if selectedOption == 1 {
                    Text("edit (first way)")
                } else {
                    Text("delete (first way)")
                }

                Divider()

                // MARK: second way
                ZStack {

                    AddView()
                        .opacity(selectedOption == 0 ? 1 : 0)

                    EditView()
                        .opacity(selectedOption == 1 ? 1 : 0)

                    DeleteView()
                        .opacity(selectedOption == 2 ? 1 : 0)
                }

                Divider()

                // MARK: showing third way
                Text("just to show, how to use third way: \(self.choosed)")

                Spacer()

            }

        }

    }

    func changeViewWithThirdWay(_ newValue: Int) {
        print("will change something in third way with: \(choosed), you can do everything in this function")
        withAnimation {
            choosed = newValue
        }

    }

}

// MARK: the third way
extension Binding {
    func onChange(_ handler: @escaping (Value) -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        return Binding(
            get: { self.wrappedValue },
            set: { selection in
                self.wrappedValue = selection
                handler(selection)
        })
    }
}
```

You'll achieve this with code snippet:

[image]

Comment: var options = ["General", "About"]
    @State private var selectedOption = 0  If I need to read data from model class and set default selected item, should I be using @Binding?

Comment: @RamyaSharma what do you mean?

Comment: Should I be using @ObservedObject if my array of options are coming from model class? Also, how to set the default state in this case ?

Comment: I get error - > Cannot use instance member 'ModelClass' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available  , if I try to set @State  var selected = ModelClass.options[0]

Comment: @RamyaSharma I think better to make another question with your code snippet and error message. It's not quite clear for me now, what you want to achieve and how you want to work with your data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681453/how-to-populate-picker-from-viewmodel-object-setting-to-initial-state-of-first

Comment: @RamyaSharma I answered - added the working solution. But read **P.S.**, you could be downvoted because of quality of question