# SwiftUI - Assign a value from a callback, display in view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm stuck on something which should be trivial, using SwiftUI. I am pulling some data back from my API, and simply want to show each item on my view with ForEach.

I have the following function:

```
@State var workoutVideoList: GetWorkoutVideoListResponse!

func GetWorkoutVideoList() {
    loadingWorkoutVideoList = true
    
    PtPodsApiService.GetWorkoutList(firebaseToken: firebaseAuthToken) { (workoutListResult) -> () in
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            workoutVideoList = workoutListResult
            loadingWorkoutVideoList = false
        }
    }
}
```

I then want to show another view and pass this object into it:

```
if workoutVideoList != nil {
    BookAppointmentView(workoutVideoList: workoutVideoList)
}
else {
    Text("Nope")
}
```

For whatever reason, my main thread sees *workoutVideoList* as nil, even though it's been assigned. I thought using the dispatcher to assign it would solve the problem, but no joy!

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Is your @State var on a ViewModel? Is your ViewModel an `@ObservableObject` if so you should change that to an `@Published`

Comment: When do you call the function? When the view appears?

Comment: @xTwisteDx It's directly in my View, I'll look into Viewmodels in SwiftUI, thanks

Comment: @Lukas When a button is pressed, the button doesn't show until `loadingWorkoutVideoList` is true

Comment: give `@State` a default value `@State var workoutVideoList: GetWorkoutVideoListResponse = false` and use `onAppear` to call `GetWorkoutVideoList()` but ideally you will eventually get this working in a ViewModel.

Comment: I've answered a MVVM question with SwiftUI here, feel free to have a look. It's very simple in Swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538721/how-to-use-mvvm-correctly-in-swiftui/67539836#67539836

Comment: @xTwisteDx I'm getting flashbacks from when I used to work with WPF, thanks will have a read!

Comment: @loremipsum I was calling the function from OnInit, moved the call to OnAppear and it's working now!! OnInit must be too early, if you want to answer the question I'll mark it as correct! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked I answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `@State` a default value `@State var workoutVideoList: GetWorkoutVideoListResponse = false` and use `onAppear` to call `GetWorkoutVideoList()` but ideally you will eventually get this working in a ViewModel.