# SwiftUI: Compact DatePicker with custom design

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I need a custom "label" with the behavior of opening the date picker in some kind of popover, even on the iPhone.

When I use the built in DatePicker with compact format, I have the behavior with opening the wheels in a popover, but I cannot customize the look of the "collapsed" version with the gray background (in fact, I can change it to some other color, but not to white e.g., it simply doesn't work).

Another option would be to have a custom `Text` wrapped inside a `Button` and then open the DatePicker, but I don't know how to achieve the popover effect on the iPhone. So I guess the first option would be the easier one, but how can I achieve a custom layout for the compact date picker? Nothing super fancy, just something like this:

[image]

instead of something like this

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit hacky, but another approach would be setting the actual `DatePicker` view's opacity to `0.011` (this is the minimum opacity value I found that can hide it well and still keep it functional), then putting it above your customized view with `.overlay`, here is an example:

```
struct MyDatePicker: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        
        // Put your own design here
        HStack(spacing: 2) {
            Text(selectedDate.formatted(.dateTime.day().month().year()))
                .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .semibold))
        
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .font(.system(size: 9, weight: .bold))
        }
        .padding(8)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous).foregroundColor(.blue))

        // Put the actual DataPicker here with overlay
        .overlay {
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {}
                .labelsHidden()
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .opacity(0.011)             // <<< here
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Excellent solution thanks

Comment: Great idea thanks!

Answer (score 5):

its more of a proof of concept, but this might be a way:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPicker = true
    @State var selectedDate = Date()

        Button {
            withAnimation {
                showPicker.toggle()
            }
        }  label: {
            Text(Text(selectedDate.getFormattedDate(format:"HH:mm:")))
                .padding()
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.gray)
                )
        }
        .background(
            DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                .clipped()
                .background(Color.gray.cornerRadius(10))
                .opacity(showPicker ? 1 : 0 )
                .offset(x: 50, y: 90)
               ).onChange(of: selectedDate) { newValue in
                   
                   withAnimation {
                       showPicker.toggle()
                   }
               }
}
```

Note that DidSet or willSet is not possible for Objects, however, we had a nice workaround [onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57518852/1820553). When date changed, just toggle, done.

Comment: this is already a huge step forward, thanks for that! I have to play with `zindex` a little bit, but there seems to be a working solution for that. The only thin that's not super nice yet is that the user has to tap the Button again to hide the `DatePicker`; do you see any possibility to let them tap anywhere to hide it?

Comment: Unfortunately canceling on tap anywhere is a quite complicated matter in SwiftUI ... you can put an "almost" transparent view (opacity 0.01) behind everything and detect a tap on that.

Comment: the other way would be wrapping a UIKit UIDatePicker into an UIViewRepresentable and changing its label. But I'm not a UIKit guy :)

Comment: You can add a done button by overlay to dismiss the picker. I did.

Comment: @swalkner did you solved to hide when date selected?

Comment: @swalkner Ok, I've found a nice workaround see the updated answer.

Comment: Instead of using `.onChange()` which gets annoying, use `.onTapGesture()` which will allow you to still swipe the wheel but will hide the picker when tapped.