# Picker .onChange doesn't change when choosing default

Tags: swiftui-picker

I have pretty much same question as here:
[SwiftUI Picker onChange or equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518852/swiftui-picker-onchange-or-equivalent),
but .onChange won't solve it exactly I need.

I have wrote a question in that link, but I was told to ask a new question (as I wasn't able to find answer anywhere :(

I have this enum:

```
enum FruitTea: String, CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case peach = "Peach"
    case passionFruit = "Passion Fruit"
    case mango = "Mango"
    case greenApple = "Green Apple"
    var description: String { rawValue }
            
}
    
enum TypeOfTea: String, CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case specialTeaPresso = "Special Tea Presso"
    case teaLatte = "Tea Latte"
    case mousseSeries = "Mousse Series"
    case milkTea = "Milk Tea"
    case fruitTea = "Fruit Tea"
    var description: String { rawValue }
}
```

And this picker:

```
@State private var type: TypeOfTea = .specialTeaPresso
@State private var fruit: FruitTea = .passionFruit
Picker("Fruit Tea", selection: $fruit) {
    ForEach(FruitTea.allCases, id: \.self) {
        Text($0.rawValue).tag($0)
    }
}
.onChange(of: fruit, perform: { _ in
    type = .fruitTea
})
```

When I choose another kind of fruit tea that is already chosen, it works. But If I choose what is default value, my TypeOfTea won't change. I know why - because there was no change. But for my app clicking on Picker means choosing type. Can you please help? Thanks.

In case someone is interested in my all app:

[My app on github](https://github.com/Marcel-git666/Geicha/tree/new)

Comment: Changing to: .onReceive([self.latte].publisher.first()) { _ in
                       type = .teaLatte
                    } for each picker will just crash the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution based on:
[here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652955)

I have reduced those 5 pickers to 2. First to choose type of tea and second will show correct view using function that returns some View. Pickers had to be enclosed in AnyView().

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if I understand your problem, but as you mentioned yourself there is no change. And your `TypeOfTea` remains a constant `.fruitTea`.
But you could try something like that to actually trigger changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var type: TypeOfTea = .specialTeaPresso
    @State private var fruit: FruitTea = .passionFruit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Fruit Tea", selection: $fruit) {
                ForEach(FruitTea.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.rawValue).tag($0)
                }
            }

            Text(type.description)
        }
        .onChange(of: fruit, perform: { newFruit in
            type = newFruit.typeOfTea
        })

    }
}

struct MyPreviewProvider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


enum FruitTea: String, CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case peach = "Peach"
    case passionFruit = "Passion Fruit"
    case mango = "Mango"
    case greenApple = "Green Apple"
    var description: String { rawValue }

    var typeOfTea: TypeOfTea {
        switch self {
            case .peach:
                return .fruitTea
            case .passionFruit:
                return .teaLatte
            case .mango:
                return .mousseSeries
            case .greenApple:
                return .milkTea
        }
    }

}

enum TypeOfTea: String, CustomStringConvertible, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case specialTeaPresso = "Special Tea Presso"
    case teaLatte = "Tea Latte"
    case mousseSeries = "Mousse Series"
    case milkTea = "Milk Tea"
    case fruitTea = "Fruit Tea"
    var description: String { rawValue }
}
```

Comment: Well I think my description of problem wasn't exact. I have 5 pickers total  - each for specific type of tea (fruit, teaLatte, speciaTeaPressol, ...) each type of tea has its own kinds - so FuitTeaType has peach fruit tea, mango fruit tea, ... teaLatte has also several kinds - Matcha Tea Latte, Winter Mellon latte, ... I'm presenting pickers for. each type of tea (fruit, latte,...) but I don't know how to choose TypeOfTea while clicking on each Picker. Have a look at app on my github.